# Icons for Install / Download / Downgrade / Update / Delete / Block / Retire

Tags: icons

I need icons for the following set of actions that appear together.

**Install / Download / Update / Downgrade / Delete / Block / Retire**

However, I find it hard to find distinct icons, particularly for Download/Install/Downgrade because something like a down arrow ⬇️ works for all 3 of them.

The clearest way would be to just use text labels, but we're using icons because the interface feels cramped with full length text labels for the above.

I'm going to put in mouseover tooltips for the icons, but would like suggestions for the above 7 actions.

Answer (score 1):

I think the label is necessary.

But if you analyze the meaning of each icon, upgrade and downgrade are actions performed once the installation is done, this can graphically unify three icons: install, upgrade and downgrade, making their representation easier

[image]