# HTML Elements to use with Image and Text used as a link

Tags: accessibility, html, semantics

What are the correct HTML elements instead of just a div to use when presenting an image and text just below as one link? I would like for the image and text to be presented in an a11y correct manner.

[image: example of image and text]

Answer (score 1):

#### Figure and figcaption

```
<figure>
<a href="hyperlink>
<img src="image">
<figcaption>Text</figcaption>
</a>
</figure>
```

Comment: No, I think OP wants a text overlaid on top of an image.

Comment: @stackzebra Not based on OP's diagram or description...

Comment: You made a mistake, **the anchor needs to go around the `<figure>`** otherwise you have a `<figcaption>` as a child of an anchor element, which is not valid HTML and is likely to cause accessibility errors.

Comment: ...but works 

Comment: I'm looking to have the text appear below the image. <figure> seems to be the correct element to use. I was worried that wrapping the anchor tag would make it invalid or not accessible. @graham-ritchie, is wrapping the entire <figure> the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: It isn't the way I would do it but it is an acceptable way. Without context of the page, how many of these images and text there are etc. it is difficult to give you "the best" way of doing it. Do you have a public URL so I can see it "in situ". If not the answer would nearly always be to make the image invisible to screen readers with `alt=""` and `role="presentation"` on the image and wrap the whole thing in an anchor. Then the only thing read out by the link will be the text. Yet again, general advice but normally that is the way.

Comment: @Danielillo: Why do you answer questions that are clearly off-topic? I noticed you did one the other day too. Surely you have been around long enough to know the posting rules?

Comment: Because i'm free 

Comment: @musefan These questions are not so clear off topic to me. If you refer to the [icons question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/140354/115107), OP is not requesting a group of icons, but is referring to the meaning of each one, its possible misinterpretation or confusion and a necessary solution. My answer provides icons, but in the statement it clarifies about the content in reference to its meaning.

Comment: @Danielillo: It genuinely shocks me that you don't see that as an icon suggestion request. However, I acknowledge we are different people and often see things differently. It doesn't much bother me that you do it, I was just curious as to your reasonings. I appreciate your honesty :D

Comment: About this question, It is off-topic how to use CSS, but not to indicate the elements that are part of a solution. I guess. (I can't find a comment someone did about this subject to me once).

Comment: @Danielillo: I am pretty confident is saying that CSS is not the only definition of "implementation". If the question was "should the picture and text act as a single, clickable link" then I would say it's UX. But they have already made that decision and are now just saying "how do I make that happen/work?", which is when it becomes implementation.